# typescript property interface or string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm developing NodeJS app using typescript and tslint and i'm using an external library for Google Places API that doesnt have any DefinitelyTyped so i wrote it myself but i ran into some situation that on a callback there is error and response properties and the error property sometimes return an object or string.

i tried to do something like that:

```
callback?: (err: IGooglePlacesError | string)
```

but it didnt work and return that err.json is not found in string type.

Comment: That's right, the `json` attribute isn't available on both of the types you say `err` could be. If you *did* get a string, **accessing it would fail**. That's TS working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> but it didnt work and return that err.json is not found in string type.

You just need to type guard it out e.g.

```
 if (typeof err !== 'string') {
   // Now TypeScript will allow it
 }
```

## More

Type guard docs I wrote : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html